# What does it mean to secure something in computer security?

Tags: appsec

Can someone provide a formal and simple definition of "to secure something" in information security?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this a very, very, very short description. The answer to your question can encompass an entire set of books.

Security is about risk management. Making something secure is about lowering risk. The lowering of risk goes together with putting controls into place, each control may have a certain price and can mitigate a certain risk, by lowering the likelihood a vulnerability can have a negative impact on your assets. Assets in this context can be anything a company considers valuable, this includes systems, applications, but also people, infrastructure etc...

A and B are both valid, except A would probably depend on cost. Security costs money and it doesn't make sense to spend loads of money to secure an asset if the security costs more than the asset is worth. If the value of an asset increases over time it may make sense to "make it more secure" over time by spending more on extra controls.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant by "as secure as possible" is "as secure as possible given my knowledge and my capabilities". 
If I install an anti-virus on my system, I certainly made my system more secure. But can I say, I secured my system?

Comment: A system can never be 100% secure

Comment: @othman I'm definitely not a security expert, but I think that it depends on many things, including what your system actually is (personal laptop with no credit card info,etc.;personal laptop with credit card info,...;corporate laptop;web server;...) and how much money/resources can you invest.

Comment: @LucasKauffman no worries - just thought I'd give you a head's up

Answer (score 1):

Risk management is the key to answering this deceptively simple question. To make data (or a device) perfectly secure, one would have to erase all knowledge of it. Destroying the data/device to make it secure makes it unavailable, violating the CIA triad cited by @SilverlightFox. By using the Enigma encryption device, the Nazi made it vulnerable.

As long as the future (and life) is uncertain, "as secure as possible" is a never ending and fruitless task. So making something more secure is more to the issue of securing something. However, that raises the question: how much more secure does the data (device) need to be? How much more effort and ingenuity is appropriate to "secure the asset?"

This reminds me of the following joke:

> Two men are walking through a forest.  Suddenly, they see a bear
>   running towards them.  They turn and start running away.  But then one
>   of them stops, takes some running shoes from his bag, and starts
>   putting the on.
>           “What are you doing?” says the other man.  “Do you think you will run fast than the bear with those?”
>           “I don’t have to run faster than the bear,” he says.  “I just have to run faster than you.”

So "how much security is enough" depends on the context. That's why most homes have key locks and banks go to the trouble of installing vaults. The impact of a breach on the former - though quite personal to the homeowner - is likely less costly in total that the impact to the bank. Thanks to the measures banks take to protect the contents of their vaults (steel, alarms, guards, etc), homeowners pay banks to hold their valuables in a lock box rather than replicate the bank's security measures for their homes. The exception that proves the point is the visibly wealthy homeowner who declines to put all her valuables into the bank vault. What is the point of valuable paintings, sculpture, and jewelry if you can't enjoy it?

So how does one decide how much effort or money spent on security is enough? One tool is [Annualized loss expectancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annualized_loss_expectancy). In short, ALE is the cost (tangible and intangible) of a loss times the probability that incident will occur in a year. If the bank has $10,000 in the vault and there is a 10 percent chance of getting successfully robbed, the bank should no more (or less) than $1,000 to protect the vault. [Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/09/security_roi_1.html) points out that the calculation get complicated and messy very quickly.

Another approach is return on security investment (ROSI). Mirroring the business principle of return on investment, [The cost of a bad thing happening is called risk exposure. A security solution mitigates that risk by some percentage. Multiplying the exposure by the percentage mitigated gives the expected return.](http://www.bcs.org/content/conWebDoc/2967) Thus ROSI is used to identify the appropriate expenditure on securing an asset. However ROSI is not without its detractors, notable among them [Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/09/security_roi_1.html).

Andrew Jauquith's [Security Metrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321349989) is another worthy read on the subject. Jaquith writes on p 33 "...practitioners of ALE suffer from a near-complete inability to reliably estimate probabilities [of occurrence] or losses." You can read his clear and cogent alternatives to ALE and ROI.

Answer (score 0):

Both are applicable.

Securing something means reducing the risks associated with running such a network, system or application.

In information security the risks are often in the CIA triad - Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability. For example, an application may have a security vulnerability that affects the confidentiality of data. Securing the application against this risk would involve remediating the security vulnerability or removing the threat. However, it is not usually possible to achieve the latter. It may not be practical to make this vulnerability "as secure as possible", however the risk can be mitigated to a level that is acceptable by the business, so often the action that is taken is to make it "more secure".

Answer (score 0):

Security usually refers to secure sharing, meaning techniques of sharing certain information only with the people you want to share it with.  If you do not have anything to share, then it is easy to be secure, just do not give anyone any information about yourself.  However, that approach is quite impractical, as living and doing business require sharing certain information: financial information with business partners, medical information with doctors, identification information with business partners and government, personal information with friends and family, etc.

Usually when people talk about a 'lack of security' they are referring to a demonstrated vulnerability and usually a sever vulnerability.  In some sense, hackers, cons, fraudsters, and thieves are always testing your security, both electronic and physical.  Most of the time you, your computers, and your life are okay, you loose no information to the wrong person, and we call this 'secure'.  At other times, there is a problem, such as a break and entry in your home, or perhaps a data breach on your computer.  In this case we call this a security problem.

The process of recovering a secure situation after a breach involves risk analysis and vulnerability repair.  If you are interested in legal action, then forensics comes into play.  Fixing the security holes is fundamentally different than getting justice which involves law enforcement.  Most computer security professionals focus on fixing security holes first, and forensics second.  Although, during the vulnerability analysis phase, there is a certain amount of forensics used to discover the vulnerability, but usually it does not pass the standard used in a court of law.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of cryptography, **secure means not broken**. And **broken** means, there is a **method to decrypt better than brute force**.

And as you know, brute force is the method of desperation where you need to try all possible keys.

Comment: The question is about appsec, not the theoretical details of encryption. I know the word 'appsec' may isn't in the text, but it is the tag the OP chose.

Comment: You think that cryptography is not related to appsec?

Comment: I think you only partially (very partially) answered the question and provide no practical advice to the OP.

Comment: Yes I partially answered the question and I stated it "In terms of cryptography". Partial contribution, is a contribution anyway, right? I just added something which other answers don't have.

Comment: Yes, upon rereading the question, I see you did respond to it.